# Detect If Angular Component is "In Use"

Tags: angular

I have two angular components that run code in the background using Observable.interval.  Each component should play a sound when a given event occurs but only the component that is currently "visible" should actually play the sound.  The components are made "visible" based upon the current Route.

What is happening now is that both components play the sound and it sounds corrupted.  My thinking was that I should detect if a component is "visible" and not play the sound under that circumstance for that component.

Is there a way to detect if a component is in use, or is there another way I should be handling this requirement to play a sound?

Code, I've trimmed irrelevant code to preserve space

*ViewUpdateService* provides the observable to which the components subscribe.

```
@Injectable()
export class ViewUpdateService {
    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
        this.notifier = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)
            ? Observable.interval(250)
            : Observable.empty(); 
    }

    notifier: Observable<any>;
}
```

*ListComponent* is the first component that needs to make the sound at a given point in time

```
@Component()
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    private soundHandler(): void {
        if(!this.triggerEventOccurred)
            return;

        if(this.shouldPlaySoundIfVisible)
            this.kerching.play();
    }
    // ... removed to preserve space ...

    constructor(private viewUpdateService: ViewUpdateService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataService.getList()
            .subscribe(l => this.handle(l));

        this.viewUpdateService.notifier
                              .subscribe(t => this.soundHandler());
    }
}
```

*DetailComponent* is the second component that needs to make the sound at a different point in time

```
@Component()
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
    private soundHandler(): void {
        if(!this.triggerEventOccurred)
            return;

        if(this.shouldPlaySoundIfVisible)
            this.kerching.play();
    }
    // ... removed to preserve space ...

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private viewUpdateService: ViewUpdateService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.paramMap
            .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
                const id = params.get('id');

                if(!id)
                    return Observable.empty();

                return this.dataService.get();
            })
            .subscribe(s => this.handle(s));       

        this.viewUpdateService.notifier
                              .subscribe(t => this.soundHandler());
    }
}
```

The components are made visible using angular routing

```
export const DrawRoute: Route = {
    path: 'draw', 
    children: [
        { path: ':id', component: DetailComponent, },
        { path: '', component: ListComponent, },
    ]
};
```

Comment: What do you define as "is in use"? Whether the component is created and mounted in the DOM?

Comment: Do you cancel / unsubscribe from your observable at all?

Comment: Also, please include the relevant code in your question, ideally in the form of a minimum reproducible snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Very abstract since you haven't provided too many details.

Extract your sound playing into separate component, extract `Observable.interval` into separate service.

Use your sound playing component in your `component1` and `component2` (of which you toggle visibility through `*nfIg`) and use your `Observable.interval` in sound playing component.

Sound playing component could receive `@Input() contextType` parameter telling it which parent is using it for the case sounds should be different for `component1` and `component2`.

[UPDATE based on your added context]

Since sound playing is obviously something that's common for both components i would extract that in separate `soundPlayingComponent`, use it in parent where `ListComponent` and `DetailsComponent`are used and have those two expose `Output() playSound:EventEmitter<whateverParamsYouNeed>` to the parent based on which appropriate sound would be played.

Comment: Apologies, it was after 11pm, brain is starting to sleep ;-)  I'll provide more detail